# how to explode and exploded string

Tags: php

I've a string of text like this:

```
Intro Title ### Some description ### a link \\\ 
Intro Title Two ### Description Two ### link 2 \\\
And so ... can be infinite
```

I use explode to be able to access and the different parts of the string.

```
$test  =  explode('###', $string);

echo $test[0]; // outputs: Intro Title
echo $test[1]; // outputs:  Some description
```

and till here it's working fine. But I need to be able to access as well the second part the same way

```
echo $test[0]; // to output: Intro Title Two
```

I've tried with a foreach, but it seems to work

```
foreach ($string as $key) {
    $second = explode('\\\', $key);
}
```

I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: How does second echo get `Intro Title Two` ?

Comment: First explode by new line. then over `###` and then by `\\\ `.

Comment: Are you getting all strings in array or there is one common string for all which you need to process?

Comment: Your question is un clear

Comment: Is "Intro Title ### Some description ### a link \\\ 
Intro Title Two ### Description Two ### link 2 \\\" is a single string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string ="Intro Title ### Some description ### a link \\\ 
Intro Title Two ### Description Two ### link 2 \\\
And so ... can be infinite";

$firstExplode  =  explode('###', $string);

foreach ($firstExplode as $key) {
    $secondExplode = explode("\\\\", $key);
    var_dump($secondExplode);
}
```

Note here I use four backslashes instead of just the 3 due to escaping issues.

Comment: this is working. but If I want to access the parts of second array how it's done? something like this `$secondExplode[0][1];` or?

Comment: Just echo it out
      echo $secondExplode[0][1];
      echo $secondExplode[0][2];
      echo $secondExplode[0][3];

Comment: thank you sir, for your help. I've ended up using Anticom's approach. But your answer is more inherent with my first question. So I'll accept yours

Comment: Good one to go with :)

Answer (score 0):

## To answer you question

You can explode on the new-lines first and then in a foreach loop explode on your delimitter. Then you wouldn't even need the back slashes at the end of each line anymore.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$lines = explode("\n", $string);
foreach($lines as $line) {
  $data[$i] = explode('###', $line);
  $i++;
}
```

## To improve your code:

Unless you **really** depend on this custom file format I would recommend using a standard format like `xml`, `yml` or `json`.

The simplest approach woulr probably be `json`:

```
<?php
$string <<<EOT
  [
    { "title": "Intro Title", "Description": "Some description", "link": "a link" },
    { "title": "Intro Title 2", "Description": "Some other description", "link": "a second link" }
  ]
EOT;

$data = json_decode($string, true);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: I agree this is probably the way to go. It's easier to the user, as well, to enter the right info in the right place. I think I'll go in this direction and use json. thank you Sir!

Comment: You're welcome! As i mentioned you can use `xml`, `yaml` or whatever else floats your boat. However `json` is one of the simplest ways to de-/serialize structured data.

Comment: thank you sir, for your help. I've ended up using your approach. But RemanBroder's answer was more helpful and inherent with my first question. So accepted his answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it is one string :

```
$string ="Intro Title ### Some description ### a link \\\ 
    Intro Title Two ### Description Two ### link 2 \\\
    And so ... can be infinite";
$string_parts = explode("\\\",$string);
foreach($string_parts as $key=>$val){
    $temp = explode('###', $val);
    echo $temp[0]; // outputs: Intro Title
    echo $temp[1]; // outputs:  Some description
}
```